# Нужно ли добавлять в requirements.txt зависимости зависимостей (рекурсивно)?

Tags: python, pip

У меня есть небольшой репозиторий, в котором хранятся принятые в команде стандарты кодирования Python в форме конфигурации pylint. Также там есть инструкция и requirements.txt для установки через pip:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Очевидно, что в requirements.txt должен быть pylint. Но [официальная документация по pylint](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylint) явно указывает, что для работы pylint необходим ещё и пакет astroid.

Я убедился, что команда `pip install pylint` успешно устанавливает astroid и остальные зависимости:

До:

```
(venv)➜  pip list 
pip (7.1.2)
setuptools (18.2)
wheel (0.24.0)
```

После:

```
(venv)➜  pip list
astroid (1.4.6)
colorama (0.3.7)
lazy-object-proxy (1.2.2)
pip (7.1.2)
pylint (1.5.6)
setuptools (18.2)
six (1.10.0)
wheel (0.24.0)
wrapt (1.10.8)
```

Вроде бы всё и так работает. Но ведь зависимость по какой-то причине явно указана в документации, и даже дана отдельная инструкция по установке.

Вопрос: должен ли я добавить astroid и прочие зависимости в requirements.txt? Есть ли стандарт, который даёт однозначный ответ на этот вопрос?

Comment: Возможно зависимость явно указана для случая ручной установки pylint?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian возможно. Но тогда про остальные 4 зависимости забыли.

Comment: Материалы для будущего ответа: https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files https://caremad.io/2013/07/setup-vs-requirement/

Answer (score 4):

1. Не удалось найти PEP, регламентирующего это.
2. Зато есть [документация](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files) к pip. Цитата:

> Requirements files are used to hold the result from [pip freeze](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_freeze/#pip-freeze) for the
>   purpose of achieving [repeatable installations](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#repeatability). In this case, your
>   requirement file contains a pinned version of everything that was
>   installed when pip freeze was run.

Файл зависимостей используется для сохранения результатов команды pip freeze, чтобы достигнуть одинаковой повторяемой установки. В этом случае в файл зависимостей помещается всё, что было получено от pip freeze с явно указанными версиями.

> Using pip freeze to generate the requirements file will ensure that
>   not only the top-level dependencies are included but their
>   sub-dependencies as well, and so on.

Если вы используете pip freeze для генерации файла зависимостей, то туда помещаются не только зависимости верхнего уровня, но также и зависимости зависимостей и т. д.

То есть файл зависимостей призван собрать зависимости для всего окружения, для всего-всего. Напротив, если использовать install_requires в setup.py (то есть только для одного приложения), то в нем не рекомендуется указывать под-зависимости. Источник - http://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/requirements/#requirements-files

Comment: Из минусов этого подхода - пакеты со временем протухают (особенно зависимости) и потом точную картину уже можно не восстановить

Answer (score 2):

Нет, не нужно.
Если разработчики других пакетов указали у себя зависимости(а обычно это так), то pip сам установит их.