# Зависимости в Python - как создать аналог package.json?

Tags: python

Вопрос такой - если ли возможность в Python создать файл-аналог package.json для того чтобы если скрипт использует либы, которых нету на данном ПК, можно было бы одной командой их поставить?

Comment: Командой [pip freeze](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_freeze/).

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev спасибо, работает)

Comment: Связанный вопрос - [Нужно ли добавлять в requirements.txt зависимости зависимостей (рекурсивно)?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/533258/Нужно-ли-добавлять-в-requirements-txt-зависимости-зависимостей-рекурсивно)